# Migrating the presentation layer from ASP.NET Web Pages to WebAPI (or MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webpages

In the last couple of years Microsoft has been pushing a lot **MVC** and **WepAPI** suggesting to leave the old technology of the Web Pages.

I am starting a brand new project using deeply the **WebAPI** technology, but my main difficulty now is toward the presentation layer of the web app: The **"old" Web Controls** have a lot of features such as grid views, built-in sorting functionalities, built-in pagination, etc. that I have not found elsewhere.

I looked at **Angular.JS** and stuff like that, but my understanding is that they just simplify what you have to create by yourself (thing to the pagination, for example).

I need some suggestions for the presentation side of a Rich Web Application possibly having a real pre-built example to start from. Microsoft has just example focusing in the server side part.

Comment: I was in the same situation, when I started MVC / WebAPI, and now I dont even look back to the traditional ASP.NET Web Forms. There are plenty of javascript plug-ins/libraries available which provides better functionalities than the ASP.NET server controls. For one of the application, we have used plain HTML / Javascript / Knockout.js / SlickGrid.js for implementing the UI and it interacts with our WebAPI for data using ajax asynchronous calls. The response was very fast. Basically, the app which we have created is following the SPA model.

Comment: I am investigating this options. I will keep all updated. Thank you